# Регулярное выражение js

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение. Должны быть допустимы все буквы и цифры, знаки препинания, пробелы(но не вначале строки). Перенос строки.
Строка может состоять из нескольких слов.

Comment: А в чём собственно проблема?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что 1. Тут уйма подобных вопросов, в которые надо порсто заглянуть. 2. В вопросе не показаны попытки сделать самостоятельно. 3. Вопрос не затрагивает ничего кроме основы, расписанной даже в википедии. 4. Вопрос не представляет ценности ни для кого кроме автора.

Comment: А вот минус не мой.

Comment: @Qwertiy Их уже два. Один мой. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я считаю, что это отличный вариант ответа на данный вопрос:
https://habrahabr.ru/post/115825/
Язык Python, но основные принципы разжёваны в самом начале.

Comment: Эм.. Язык не тот...

Comment: А есть разница в принципах построения регулярок? Я так же и на php писал, всё работает.

Comment: 1. Иногда бывает. 2. Статья преимущественно расписывает работу с регулярками, методы и всё в этом духе. По синтаксису там очень мало. Может быть проще заглянуть в википедию и посмотреть краткую табличку.

Comment: @Qwerty 1- не сталкивался, согласен. 2 - Просто табличка из википедии мне не помогла. Разобрался только после прочтения данной статьи, хотя, Ваша правда, возможно, именно примеры больше всего и помогли.